# Allow login using WordPress functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, react-native, authentication, web-deployment

We have a website built on WordPress with over 10,000 customers/users registered in it.
Now we are trying to build a mobile application for these customers/users using react-native but we don't want them to register again or create new user to use that application. Mobile application do not have register screen; we only want to allow users to login who already have created account via website. Is there any way for the users to use same ID and password as WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You should use rest api. Here is first step https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/